# Which is more idiomatic (or neither)

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

Which way of saying *Who knows how to say milk in German?* is more idiomatic (or neither if they both aren't)?
"Qui sait dire le lait en Allemand?"
"Qui sait comment on dit le lait en Allemand?"

Comment: If translating, I always would add word: Qui sait dire le mot lait en [langue]. You don't need it in English, though.

Comment: *die Milch* ! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If written  as such,  neither is correct, but after a small modification both are.

- Qui sait dire « le lait » en allemand ?
- Qui sait comment on dit « le lait » en allemand ?

Those next two written forms are also correct, but then the article is not asked in the translation.

- Qui sait dire « lait » en allemand ?
- Qui sait comment on dit « lait » en allemand ?

As spoken sentences only the last pair is readily understandable unless the speaker uses a careful pronunciation which makes it clear that the article is part of the combination. Moreover, if it is not known that one is talking about a liquid, spoken language is ambiguous in the case of the first two pairs, and some other way is needed (*Someone might understand « laid ».*).

- Qui sait dire « lait » en allemand, c'est à dire le liquide que l'on obtient par la traite des vaches ?
- Qui sait comment on dit « lait » en allemand,  c'est à dire le liquide que l'on obtient par la traite des vaches ?

Comment: Pour lever l'ambigüité avec *laid* ou *les*, on dirait aussi simplement : Comment dit-on le lait (de vache)?

Answer (score 2):

> Qui sait comment dire/on dit « du lait » en allemand ?
>  Comment on
> dit/dit-on « du lait » en allemand ? [Focusing on what you want to know
> instead of who knows this.]